# Copy a file on server and make it accessible

Tags: java, html

I have a jersey web service. I am trying to download a file on my hard disk through my localhost Tomcat server.

```
window.open("D:\\mario.zip");
```

This line doesn't work due to security reason.
My 2nd try is creating a folder in the project which can be accessible like localhost/myfolder then I put a file there which can be accessed through http.
Now I copy files from a specific folder to "myfolder" so that they can be downloaded.

The problem is: although the files exist in my hard drive, they cannot be accessible through http. Only after I refresh the project in Eclipse. The files can be accessible through http.

Is there any trigger for the server to update its file list?

Comment: `window.open`? Are you confusing Java and JavaScript?

Comment: If you can directly access a file through javascript, then what's the point of Security? No such browser will let you directly access a file through javascript unless permitted by the User ..

Comment: I have updated my question. I only try to access a file in a "broadcasted" folder on my server. I use Java to copy my file from the specific folder to the "broadcasted" folder for downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do you create "Aliases" in Apache Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350901/how-do-you-create-aliases-in-apache-tomcat)

This is the answer. I don't know much about other solution than creating an "alias" as in Apache server. Olaf Kock's answer would be interesting too if he can be more beginner-friendly.

Further notice, you can find server.xml in your Tomcat server "project" in Eclipse.